# Footer not staying at the bottom when scrolling

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


header{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}


section{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0.5rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    width: 80%;
    
}

footer{
    background: #000;
    color: wheat;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<header>Hello</header>

<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

<footer>this is a footer</footer>
</body>
```

The footer in the css is not sticking to the bottom of the page when I scroll..

[image]

How to fix this?
I want it to always be at the bottom of the page regardless of the fact if user is able to scroll or not. `position : sticky;` is not what I want to use. Also if someone can point where I have made the mistake and what is the best way to do it.
Thanks

edit : page refers to the entire web page.. Not just the visible part..

Also, to be clear, let me mention again :

The footer should always stay at the bottom of the web page.. If I can scroll, the footer should be seen when I reach the bottom end of the page and if there is not enough content to scroll, the footer should not be right below the section, rather it should be at the end of the webpage

Comment: Use `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: That does not help.. If I am able to scroll, it is seen.. I want it to be stuck to the bottom of the page even if I scroll down

Comment: you want it always to be down ? meaning that when the scroll bar is up you will not see the  footer ?

Comment: yep @Ben.S also when there is no scroll bar, I still want it to be at the bottom of the page

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh when you say page do you mean visible part or the entire webpage?

Comment: The entire web page.. Sry not to mention clearly

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh so i don't get what is the problem with `position: fixed; bottom: 0 `
_An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled._ [example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed)

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh so if is the entire web page don't set any possition or put `position static`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do that

1st way

```
body {
  margin-bottom: 100px; //Height of footer
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

2nd way

```
footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

3rd way:- Make your own custom scroll container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <header>Hello</header>

    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>


    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>




    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>




    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>


    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>




    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam
        minus
        hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus
        cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut
        ex
        laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
  </div>


  <footer>this is a footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  background: #000;
  color: wheat;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.scrollable {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 92px); /*Subtract height of footer*/
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: it's looks like this is not what the question is asking, see comments below the question

Comment: @Ben.S I got the question now. Change min-height instead of max-height inside .scrollable class. You will get your desire result. In that case, overflow is not required on the .scrollable class.

.scrollable {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 92px); /*Subtract height of footer*/
}

Comment: Thanks @sawannirala the 3rd option helped.. Could you please explain in detail what was the change done?

Comment: @Ben.S I just wrap all the content in a separate container except the footer. I have set the container min-height to the height of the screen minus the footer height. Because of that container height can't be sorter than the height of the screen minus the footer height. It doesn't matter weather it has content or not. When the container height content exceed the height of the screen minus the footer height, it work like normal.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** change to this:

```
footer{
    background: #000;
    color: wheat;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: initial;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  background: #000;
  color: wheat;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: initial;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Test</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>Hello</header>

  <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum
      quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
  </section>
  
  <footer>this is a footer</footer>
```

Comment: This does half the work.. If there are less sections, then the footer comes to the top and does not stick to the bottom

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh even if there are less sections the footer will be at `bottom: 0;` in what height you want it to be ?

Comment: I always want it to be at the bottom of the page

Comment: I edited the snippet to be with only one section - see if that is what you want

Comment: its in the bottom!, the page height itself is less when there are less sections!

Comment: So suppose there are 3 or 4 sections which does not occupy the whole page, the footer comes right below the section and leaves a lot of space at the bottom.. How to permanently fix the footer to the bottom of the page regardless of the scroll?

Comment: can you please edit your code sample to that case you want, because I don't understand what space are you talking about

Comment: @AayanamAnirudh I edited the solution I believe it should be good now

Answer (score 0):

Make use of flex:

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


header{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}


section{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0.5rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    width: 80%;
    
}

main {
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: auto;
}

footer {
    background: #000;
    color: wheat;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<main>
    <header>Hello</header>

    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
    
    
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
        <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
    
    
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
        <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
    
    
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
    
    
    
    
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
    </section>
</main>
<footer>this is a footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not what the question is asking, see comments

Comment: it's exactly what he wants. The footer is always on bottom, even if he scrolls. If he wants something else he should clarify.

Comment: see in comments above, if he wanted that, this would be enough `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Comment: @julianpoemp please check the comment below the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Is this what you want?

```css
 *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0.5rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    width: 80%;
    
}

footer{
    background: #000;
    color: wheat;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;

    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
header{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>Hello</header>

<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

<footer>this is a footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **position:fixed** in footer

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


header{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}


section{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0.5rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    width: 80%;
    
}

footer{
    background: #000;
    color: wheat;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<header>Hello</header>

<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>


    <section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>




<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus excepturi ullam velit culpa modi quam minus hic incidunt architecto debitis a quibusdam, eum quae officiis nisi. Obcaecati facere earum est beatae natus cupiditate corporis harum quas impedit corrupti ipsum exercitationem explicabo quidem animi fugit possimus ut ex laudantium, nostrum eos.</p>
</section>

<footer>this is a footer</footer>
</body>
```